# How can I add functionality to another button inside public class Controller in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a main screen with one buttom that opens another window. However I don't know how to make the buttom close the second window. The error that I am getting is because I am trying to handle two button within the same class (handleButtonClick). Someone could help me how to declare and add functionality to this second button? The soncend button calls closePopUp.

```
public class Controller {

    public Button signupB;
    public Label label1;
    public Button closePopUp;


    public void handleButtonClick() {

        System.out.println("Test one");
        label1.setText("This option is not available in the beta version");
        label1.setOpacity(1);

        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sceneNotAvailable.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 630, 400);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("New Window");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create new Window.", e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need some type of `if-statement` and something like `stage.isShowing()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I found the solution for this situation. I am very new to JavaFX but what I did was to declare two different classes for each button. I am not sure if this is the right way to go but it works.

```
public void handleButtonClick() {
    label1.setText("This option is not available in the beta version");
    label1.setOpacity(1);

    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sceneNotAvailable.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 630, 400);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("New Window");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create new Window.", e);
    }
}

public void Button1Action(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) closePopUp.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}
```

Comment: java naming conventions, please

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right! That is what I will do now. I am still learning. Thank you for the tip.